# Adding audio to multiple mp4 files using mp4box

Tags: batch-file, mp4box

I am trying to add the same audio file to a large number of mp4 files (that currently have NO audio stream).

I am pretty sure I have used the following code (in a .bat file) successfully in the past:

`for %%a in (*.mp4) do mp4box %%a -add 1sSilenceM.mp3 pause`

However, when I try to run it now I am getting this error:-

"Error - 2 input names specified, please check usage"

Can anyone explain why it no longer works (or tell me what is wrong with it)?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps `pause` is not supposed to be on the same line, or at least preceded with an ampersand.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmmm,

After much fiddling about (and some further research on the internet) I added quotation marks to the filename variable (%%a) after the mp4box command and this has solved the problem.  So the code now looks like this:-

```
for %%a in (*.mp4) do mp4box "%%a" -add 1sSilenceM.mp3 pause
```

I don't understand why this has now become necessary as the batch file used to run perfectly before (on Win 10 and earlier).  Could it be something to do with some update to Win 10?

Anyone who can offer any insight(s) I'd be glad to hear them.

My thanks to any & all readers/contributors.

Comment: You should always double-quote filenames because without doing so, spaces as well as other potentially problematic characters in their filenames will cause you issues. As a general rule, unless you knew for absolute certainty that none of your `.mp4` files in the current directory will never contain such characters, you should assume they do. You still seem to have `pause` at the end of the line, which, I've already advised you about, and from which you have not provided any confirmation of feedback.

Comment: As I said in my earlier "answer", adding the double quotes around '%%a' completely solved the problem and the batch runs correctly now.  

The 'pause' at the end of the line is causing no problem whatsoever, the routine only pauses once it has processed ALL the videos in the folder, so I haven't changed that.  (I suspect there may be a newline character before it anyway putting it onto a line of its own.)   


My concern was (and still is) that this batch file worked fine in the past (without ANY quotes) and I haven't needed to add the quotes to the .mp3 file being... (contd.)

Comment: (contd.) ...added (but I would always make sure that any file being 'added' had no problem characters in its filename.)

I just don't understand (and would still like to if anyone can explain it) why the batch file ran perfectly before (without any quotes) but now it suddenly needs them.

However, now it's running properly and doing what I need, I suppose I can live without the explanation, lol, but thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: I assume you suddenly ran into a file with a space in its name, whereas everything before this point was named correctly.

Comment: Nope.  There were definitely NO "illegal" characters (or spaces) in ANY of the filenames involved in the procedures I ran but thank you for taking the time to make your suggestion.

Comment: Have you read the man page, help information for `mp4box`? What I'm telling you is that unless `pause` is an additional option/parameter for it, _(it isn't, and those generally begin with a dash/hyphen)_, it should not be appended to the end of the line. If you precede it with an ampersand, you will get a `pause` prompt message after each mp4 file has been processed. If you precede it with a CRLF, _(as this is Windows)_, it will display the `pause` prompt message after all of the mp4 files have been processed. If it is showing on the same line and there is a line return there it is an LF only.

Comment: Thank you for all your comments but I have tried to explain already that the PAUSE command is NOT on the same line as the mp4box command line.     I don't know why it appeared that way when I first posted it but I will try again:-

`for %%a in (*.mp4) do mp4box "%%a" -add 0.2sSilenceM.mp3
pause`

Does that help?   As I said earlier the program executes interleaving ALL 500 videos in  the folder before finally pausing when it has completed; that is the ONLY point at which it pauses (when it's done.)!

Comment: Here is the binary for it (taken from HxD):-

66 6F 72 20 25 25 61 20 69 6E 20 28 2A 2E 6D 70 34 29 20 64 6F 20 6D 70 34 62 6F 78 20 22 25 25 61 22 20 2D 61 64 64 20 30 2E 32 73 53 69 6C 65 6E 63 65 4D 2E 6D 70 33 0D 0A 70 61 75 73 65
CR  LF  P  A   U   S   E

(I do hope that has displayed correctly, lol.)  Does that now convince you that the PAUSE command is on a separate line?

Comment: I'm sorry to keep disagreeing with your; I realize you are trying to be helpful but the proof of the pudding is in the eating and, as I say, the batch file DOES NOT pause until it has completed its run through ALL the video files in the folder.

Thank you for your time & trouble; I appreciate your efforts and understand the point(s) you are making but I'm afraid you are barking up the wrong tree here; there's no problem with the PAUSE placement.

Cheers.

Comment: The system here still refuses to show the code as being on two separate lines (weirdly) and I tried to put  "CR LF P A U S E" immediately underneath the Hex "0D 0A 70 61 75 73 65 " but, of course, once I posted the comment the alignment was all changed, lol.

Comment: To add a code sample to your question or answer, paste your code, or manually type it _(using the enter/return key of your keyboard at the end of each line)_, then highlight your block of code, and click on the Code Sample button, **`{}`**.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any "Code Sample button" when adding 'comments' so I used 'back ticks'.  I also pasted my entire code in one go so perhaps that's why the PAUSE shows up on the same line (perhaps too because what I'm pasting is simply text from a batch file rather than true "code"?) but I will tr again, lol.

`for %%a in (*.mp4) do mp4box "%%a" -add 0.2sSilenceM.mp3
pause`

Hopefully that may now show up correctly?

Comment: Nope!  Still keeps showing the PAUSE on the same line.  I give up!  Please be assured, the placement of the  PAUSE command does not interfere with the running of the batch file.